# Why next Script tag function once only?

Tags: reactjs, next.js

Can u tell me why script below works only when is first page load? When i go to another page and go back i see there is no captcha and cant send a form.

```
import Script from "next/script";
function Contact(){
return(<>
    <Head>
        <title>Kontakt</title>
        <meta name="description" content="Formularz kontaktowy. Napisz wiadomość" />   
    </Head>
 <Script  src="https://www.google.com/recaptcha/api.js"></Script>
</>
}
```

but whe i use script like below it works fine

```
import Script from "next/script";
function Contact(){
return(<>
    <Head>
        <title>Kontakt</title>
        <meta name="description" content="Formularz kontaktowy. Napisz wiadomość" />   
        <script  src="https://www.google.com/recaptcha/api.js"></script>
    </Head>
</>
}
```

I tried all strategy's load but it doesnt help.

Comment: The first one uses next.js's `Script` component, but omits its `strategy` attribute that controls when it loads.  The second one is a plain old html `<script>` tag.

Comment: yes its absolutely true but as i mentioned I tried all strategy's load but it doesnt help.  Even if there is no strategy passed as attr next sets default strategy